# What documents should I take to the interview for my US B2 visa application?

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, paperwork, b1-b2-visas, applications

I am an Indian house wife planning to visit USA for 3 weeks with my husband holding B1/B2 tourist visa. He is working as an Engineer in Dubai and visited USA once. I am holding holding UAE residence visa since 3 years.

My husband own brother is in New Jersey and he can send invitation letter to me. We are planning to stay at their home for 3 weeks.

Please suggest me the chances of getting USA B2 visa for house wife and also any suggestions to carry documents for visa interview?

Appreciate your valuable feedback.

Thanks & Best Regards,
Priya

Comment: "Note: Visa applicants must qualify on the basis of the applicant's residence and ties abroad, rather than assurances from U.S. family and friends. A letter of invitation or Affidavit of Support is not needed to apply for a visitor visa. If you choose to bring a letter of invitation or Affidavit of Support to your interview, please remember it is not one of the factors used in determining whether to issue or deny the visa."

Comment: To my previous comment, I would add that a letter from your brother in law is probably worth having in hand, even if there's only a very small chance that it would be useful.  If the officer suspects that you're lying about visiting your brother in law, the letter could help dispel that suspicion.  But the likelihood that the officer would develop such a suspicion is low, and if there *is* such a suspicion, the likelihood that it is the only problem with the application is also low.  I posted that comment mainly to show that such a letter is not *required* and that its value is small.

Answer (score 2):

The required presumption under U.S. law is that every visitor visa applicant is an intending immigrant until they demonstrate otherwise. Therefore, the documents you present must overcome this presumption by demonstrating:

- That the purpose of your trip is to enter the United States temporarily for business or pleasure;
- That you plan to remain for a specific, limited period;
- Evidence of funds to cover expenses in the United States;
- That you have a residence outside the United States as well as other binding ties that will ensure your departure from the United States at the end of the visit.

https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html

This https://de.usembassy.gov/interview-and-supporting-documents/ will help you figure out the documents you need and how to approach the interview https://de.usembassy.gov/interview-and-supporting-documents/ (thanks to @Phoog for the link)

As to your chances of getting the visa, no-one can predict that.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the DS-160 allows the applicant to upload only a photograph.  The only way to submit supporting documents is to bring them to the interview.  See for example [Interview and Supporting Documents: What you Say Matters More Than What You Show!](https://de.usembassy.gov/interview-and-supporting-documents/) from the US embassy in Germany: "If an officer would like to view your documents, he/she will ask for them during the interview."

Comment: @Phoog Thank you, I have amended my answer.

Comment: I learned of this relatively recently.  I suspect there are many more answers here that will need to be amended.

Comment: @Phoog Do we have a community wiki for the US, along the lines of the ones existing for Schengen and UK?

Comment: A general one for visitor visa applicants? I'm not even aware of those for the Schengen or UK.  I am mostly familiar with various canonical "transit visa" questions.  But it would definitely be useful to have one.  Perhaps we should discuss it in chat or in meta.