# Visa processing for attending company conference at US while working remotely from Bangladesh

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, remote-locations, bangladesh, software

I work for a US software company remotely from Bangladesh and my employer wants me to join a conference with a partner company investing in our company.

My employer booked air-tickets, hotel reservation part of the conference and I book a hotel in LA outside conference days.

I submitted the D160 form myself and applied for a B2 Business visa that is the sole purpose and my employer will be sending an invitation letter before the interview at embassy that I will take with me for an interview.

Is there anything employer should mention in the invitation letter and any other paperwork or invitation should send to the embassy directly (again, non-immigrant visa)or is there anything I am missing??

I know their many software engineers work remotely for US software company 
from other countries and help from experienced will be appreciated.

Comment: B-2 is a tourist visa.  For a business visit, you need a B-1 visa or a combination B-1/B-2 visa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've faced interviews at the US Embassy in Dhaka twice (in a span of five years) and both times it was for attending tech conferences/company retreats in the US.

You should present all the documents related to your work (any contract letter) along with the invitation letter when you go to the interview.

Also, make sure to keep some of the other paperwork like utility bills, bank statements, etc. Although they don't specifically ask for these, it may be useful to keep them in hand. Sometimes the consular officer will ask you to see if you have strong financial ties to the country which will prompt you to come back. So presenting those, in that case, will be helpful.

As for what to include in the invitation letter, it should mention that your role at the company, your full name and address, how long you've been working for them, the purpose of the travel, who will bear the expenses, and the fact that you won't be employed during your stay in the US (as that's illegal). In other words, the invitation letter should clearly tell the consular officer what you do, what that company does, why you need to visit the US, the purpose of the conference, and when you'll return to your home country.

Your employer shouldn't send those directly to the embassy. You'll have to carry it with you when you face the interview. The US embassy does not mention specifically which documents should be brought with you. They just say supporting documents, and these will be whatever documents you think will help your case.

Hope that helps.

Sajib,

https://ais.blog

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/142490/what-documents-should-i-take-to-the-interview-for-my-us-b2-visa-application/142492#142492