# Visa Refusal, Planning on trying again

Tags: usa, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas, nigerian-citizens

I have been refused visas for the US B1/B2 once. Now i want to try again.

- I am not married but i am in Civil Union for 2 years
- I have 2 jobs (One Remote for the US and one Onsite where I work for a Bank as a software Developer)
- My take home Monthly for the 2 jobs summounts to 870,000 Naira / month and 10,440,000 Annually
- But i do not have a travel history?

Do you think I stand a good chance for a US B1/B2 Visa at this point? I am from Nigeria

Comment: You haven't said why you were refused before. Unless you address that, you're likely to be refused again. Beyond that, we have no idea what your chances are.

Comment: the visa officer just asked me if i was married and if I have traveled before. I replied by saying no, and he handed me a blue paper. he did not even take time to have a look at my documents

Comment: Unfortunately, Nigeria is generally rated as high risk from an immigration point of view. This https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/142490/what-documents-should-i-take-to-the-interview-for-my-us-b2-visa-application/142492#142492 may help you better understand the hurdles you need to overcome to secure a visa

Comment: @Traveller, very bad. Funny enough dude did not even look at my ID or documents. Do you think I should abandon or try maybe as third country?

Comment: @Hamish An interview is a mandatory part of the application process for a US (visitor) visa, probably the reason the officer didn’t even look at your documents is that the refusal decision was already made. Your only real hope is to build up a travel history and stronger ties to home. No point reapplying until your circumstances are different IMHO

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Arthur's Pass' comment above. Because we don't see the prior refusals, and you've not provided much information in your question, we're just guessing. You could help us by posting a scan of your refusal letter, with personal identification data obscured. Still, I'll add a few observations.

The evaluator is looking for ties to your home country, that is, reasons that tend to show you'll leave when supposed to, and not stay on in the US to work and live undocumented. Under US law, the evaluator must presume that your real intent is to immigrate to the United States, and it is your burden to convince the evaluator that you do not wish to immigrate and will leave the US when you should.

Your ties to your home country are weak. You have no travel history to demonstrate your trustworthiness. While you're in a Civil Union, it's possible or likely that the evaluator will see a civil union as a weaker connection than a marriage. You don't apparently own real property in your home country, or have children there. While you have a job, you don't disclose if you've had the local job long enough that it might be considered "permanent," nor what proportion of your income comes from the local job. Your remote job is not a "tie" to your home country, as remote work can be done anywhere. Finally, we have no idea whether your bank statements support the income you declare, or disclose other financial actions (such as unexplained transactions, either repeated or of significant amount) which suggest that you and your circumstances are not exactly as you represent.

You haven't disclosed how long you intend to stay in the US, and how much you expect to spend. Applicants who plan to spend either too little to support the trip (food and lodging in the US can be extremely expensive), or say they'll spend on a single trip some significant proportion of their earnings or savings, are both disfavored.

I believe you are a poor candidate for a US visa. Because serial refusals (especially short-term serial refusals) increase the liklihood of future refusals, you should not apply again until **all of the issues with any prior visa application or applications** have been addressed and corrected.

To learn more about the issues mentioned in this answer, use the "Search on Travel" box at the top of the page and search for "US visa refusal" and "ties to home country."

Comment: The OP is asking about B1/B2 visas, which is a US visa, not a UK one. He also says he's been refused once, but you refer to 'both prior applications'. Your answer is confusing for these reasons, even if your advice is generally good.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass Thanks, I read the question too quickly and erred as to UK/US. The OP said "visas" and "once" in the same sentence. I saw the plural, and not the singular. I'll amend the answer on these issues.